# Angular 2 Routing | How to make routerLink override param and add param when necessary?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

My routing looks like this:

```
name/lastname/:id
```

And currently my URL is:

```
name/lastname
```

And I have a list of anchors:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of list">
    <a [routerLink]="{item.id}"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When I click once on an anchor, my url changes to:

```
name/lastname/123
```

My problem is that when I click once more, I want to configure that I am changing an existing param, because now I get the following:

```
name/lastname/123/123
```

Answer (score 0):

Its the simplest way to pass parameters in a router link.

```
<a [routerLink]="['name/lastname', item.id]"></a>
```

Value used in *routerLink* parameter will be appended to end your present path, if you use an undeclared link in your rourter configuration. It's reason why you get link like name/lastname/23/23